# Texture Resize Problem into Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

We have some problem when we import Obj with PNG & MTL file inside the Autodesk Forge Viewer.

We expected to see this Image quality:

[External Program quality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXgof.png)

Instead the result is this one:

[Forge Viewer- using the same files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKIaF.jpg)

We need to know how, if it's possible, to avoid the Resize of the texture inside the forge viewer

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that there's no way to configure the Model Derivative service in this regard. Textures are always resized down to - I believe - 256x256px.

One thing you *could* try is modifying the material during runtime. The Forge Viewer APIs allow you to [modify materials of your model elements](https://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/03/add-material-to-built-in-object-in-viewer-by-autodesk-view-data-api.html), so you could create a new `THREE.Material` with your high-res texture and apply it to the corresponding element as soon as the model is loaded into the viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Tanks Petr, It works for me,

If anyone need to try use this simple function to test it:

```
function newTexture() {    
   
    var mats = NOP_VIEWER.impl.matman()._materials;       
    
    for (index in mats) {

        
        m = mats[index];    
        m.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('YOUR IMAGE URL');   
        m.needsUpdate = true; 
    }

    NOP_VIEWER.impl.invalidate(true, true, false);
}
```